# Moving / Migrating SharePoint 2007

Tags: migration

Can someone help me please? I need to move 18 SharePoint servers (mainly 2007) and about 50 databases from one datacenter to another. It is like for like from VM to VM. I know this should be relatively simple but I don’t know what to do or even where to start. Can anyone give me any guidelines of things I need to do? Questions I should answer before I start…etc

Thanks in advance!

AJ

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started : http://technet.microsoft.com/library/cc303422%28office.12%29.aspx

Have a look a this specific section : http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262370%28v=office.12%29 (Move and migrate servers and server farms (Office SharePoint Server 2007))

> Moving procedures
>
> The following articles provide information to help you move an Office
>   SharePoint Server 2007 farm, databases, and other components:
>
> - Move to another farm (Office SharePoint Server 2007)
> - Move an SSP to another farm (Office SharePoint Server 2007)
> - Move services to a new server or farm (Office SharePoint Server 2007)
> - Move all databases (Office SharePoint Server 2007)
> - Move content databases (Office SharePoint Server 2007)